# Is it possible to program LED strip?

Tags: led, molex

I bought a LED strip that uses molex connector to work.
Is it possible to somehow control the strip from my computer and program it in some way to make it blink, fade etc.

Here are few pictures of the strip:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Probably.  As it stands though this is too broad a question. How to do it is a topic that would fill a book and would depend on what tools and development environments you have available.  What have you tried? What problems have you faced?

Comment: From the pic there's only 2 of those pins connected anyway -- I'm wondering if this is even a programmable LED strip, or it's simply powered on or off? - You need to go back and look at what you've brought - i don't think it's the right thing, nor it's what you think it is.

Comment: @djsmiley2k if one could alter the current, and script it, it would in essense be a programmable led strip which could blink or fade in/out, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @djsmiley2k yeah I just need to control the current so I can turn it on/off basically..

Comment: You wont be able to do that from a PC without additional hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  PCs are not designed for pulse width modulation (PWM), which provides the ability to blink and dim LEDs.

However, you can use an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) or [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) to program LEDs to do such things.